# npm library fails to install in GitLab CI

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, npm-install, gitlab-ci-runner

My Docker image build has been failing to build lately and I've managed to trace down
where exactly it struggles.

When the runner is executing `RUN npm install react-scripts@2.1.8 -g --silent --no-optional` (from Dockerfile)
it fails and gives no error output to work with. Job log shows no clue as to why it failed.

I figured I could SSH into the CI server but GitLab doesn't support direct SSH access into CI server for debugging purposes.

My question is how can I debug this ? What steps I should take ? I don't deal every day with
bug where I get no error output.

What are the conditions in which GitLab runner may fail to install it ?

**Note:**
I ran it locally and no problem whatsoever hence it must be problem within the CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timeout of the build runner was to blame in this particular case. As soon as I reorganized the code in build script npm library was successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

is the build of your image is ok in your computer ? You can also install a gitlab runner in your computer to test your gitlabci file

Comment: I thought of that. Unfortunately GitLab runner doesn't accept build flags when used locally. Flags I need to use. But good thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `--silent` flag from the `npm install` command.  I reckon you'll see a bit more then.

Comment: Yep. I've thought of that. As turned out the issue was timeout of the build runner. The build process itself was fine.

Comment: Okay, great. Nice work.  Thanks for posting an answer!